# Use QMessageBox to choose from a list of options

Tags: java, qt, joptionpane, qmessagebox

I'm newly moving from Java to Qt, and I have a question.  In JOptionPane you can pass an array of choices and JOptionPane will automatically make a combo box for the user to select a choice from.  Is something analogous to this possible in Qt with QMessageBox or another native Qt element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`QInputDialog::getItem()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qinputdialog.html#getItem). For example:

```
QStringList fruits;
fruits << "Apple" << "Banana" ... ;
QString fruit = QInputDialog::getItem(this, "Select fruit", "Fruit:", fruits);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could just read QMessageBox [reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html).

I am copy-pasting code sample from it:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
 msgBox.setText("The document has been modified.");
 msgBox.setInformativeText("Do you want to save your changes?");
 msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);
 msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Save);
 int ret = msgBox.exec();
 switch (ret) {
   case QMessageBox::Save:
       // Save was clicked
       break;
   case QMessageBox::Discard:
       // Don't Save was clicked
       break;
   case QMessageBox::Cancel:
       // Cancel was clicked
       break;
   default:
       // should never be reached
       break;
 }
```

This code creates a message box with three buttons (Save, Discard, Cancel). Save button is focused.

You can combine values from [Standard buttons](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum) using bitwise OR operator in setStandardButtons function.

If you need some options known only at runtime I can propose this possible solution.

```
QMessageBox msgBox;

//set common message box parameters. (informative text, etc)

//iterate through possible options. For each possible option:
{
  QPushButton *button = msgBox.addButton(myQStringOption, QMessageBox::AcceptRole);
  connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), /* response object */, SLOT(/*response slot*/));
}

msgBox.exec();
```

I am not sure this is the most elegant solution but it should works.

If you don't want to use signals and slots you could use clickedButton() method to determine which button was pressed.

```
msgBox.exec();

if ((msgBox.clickedButton())->text() == myQStringOption){
  //doStuff
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer.  What I have is an arbitrary list of QStrings, and I want the user to select one of them.  This list can be long or short, and I don't know the contents of it until runtime.  I read the documentation and I saw this example however this does not seem to address my problem because it only provides 3 choices and they are not arbitrary, they are predefined by QMessageBox.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your question first time. I can propose to use addButton() function. I'll update my answer soon with short example.

Comment: As shown in the documentation you can directly do this comparison: `if( msgbox.clickedButton() == button )`

Comment: I know this. But in this task I think we are interested in what option was choosen and it is unnesessery to store somewhere information about created buttons. Don't forget, buttons are created dynamically, we don't have option1Button, option2Button and optionKButton. The best we can have is QList <QAbstractButton*>. I think that vote down is incorrect in this case.